# Exact meaning of dB?

Tags: noise, decibel

I know that when people say that a gain of amplifier is X dB, they mean that  10*log(Pout/Pin).

However, How can I interpret it when they say that "noise floor is -120dB"? How can I derive voltage level?

Comment: You need to know that 0 dBm is 1 mW into 600 Ohms.  Find out what voltage 0 dBm equates to (I'm not going to tell you), then work out what the voltage level is 120 dB below that voltage.  Easy Peasy.

Comment: One Decibell is a tenth of a Bell .One Bell was a big unit named after Alexandra Graham Bell.dB is the accepted unit these days.

Comment: @DwayneReid - Sorry, no. High-speed ADCs, for instance, are often speced as having a noise floor xx dB below full scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically the noise floor is the ratio of the noise with input shorted to the maximum output.

If you have an amplifier capable of 1V RMS output and the noise floor is -120dB then the noise is 1uV RMS at the output with the input shorted. Use \$20\log(\frac{V_N}{V_{MAX}})\$ since it is voltage, not power.

Divide by the gain to get the input-referred noise voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Know that people often speak imprecisely. In this case they may be conflating (or you are hearing) dB when the actual figure is dBm (where, as Dwayne notes, 0 dBm is one milliwatt.)

Alternatively, this may be a "signal to noise" figure, unitless. If the signal is X, the noise is 120 dB less than X.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used dB in terms of a known reference level. LED sound level meters usually have 3dB spacing between LED's, representing watts rms.
 The actual wattage used is known by the sound engineer who set up the mics and amps and speakers. He or she would adjust the sound board and amplifier gain so the top red LED's indicate the limit of the existing hardware.
 *So dB is always a relative term, as it is a comparison of 2 sound or power levels*. It is not normally used to represent voltage or current directly (linear), but rather very large changes in voltage or current or wattage. 
-3dB is a drop to 70.7% in power, another -3dB is 70.7% of that value, or a 50% drop overall in just 2 steps. That's why dB is used so often, but the details of each dB are buried in the hardware it is reading from. 
This is not the same as dBm, which has already been exlained.

Comment: That is all true, but it doesn't really address @Steve's question.

Comment: As I said, while you offered a decent description of decibels, the question is about specifically what is meant by noise being 120dB down. And that is rather a nebulous question which can't be answered precisely even if we know exactly what decibel means.

Comment: @RichardCrowley. Thx for the vote of confidence. I agree with you and maybe some others that saying '120dB down' has no meaning without knowing what the reference point is, usually as it relates to existing hardware. 0dBm is the only fixed ref I know of.

Comment: Just as a side-note, when Mt. Krakatoa exploded early last century it's SPL (sound pressure level) was estimated to be 180dB. Enough to turn bone into powder. Everyone for 30 miles lost their hearing for at least 1 hour. So much for 120dB.

Comment: "_... representing watts rms._" I don't think there's any such thing. It's just watts.

Comment: @transistor. As opposed to watts p-p, which would be 1.414 times the RMS value for a pure sine wave. Normally this is a running average value.

Comment: I don't think so. (1) We use RMS for voltage and current when we want the equivalent DC that would give the same heating effect in a resistor. (I'll stay with resistors for this discussion.) (2) Since power is VI we've done the squaring so we just have to get the mean and don't have to get the square root. (3) The peak power generated by a sine product, therefore, would be \$ \sqrt {2}V \sqrt {2} I = 2 VI \$ or twice the average. (4) P-P doesn't make sense because the product of the negative half-cycles is positive. You just get peak to zero (P-0) which is just "peak power".

Comment: @transistor. No disputing the math, but most often I am simply using meters that read in decibels/RMS if AF or RF signals, or linear scaled if reading volts, amps, ohms, etc. I don't bother with the math unless we are using the meters at their limits. I don't use P-P unless it is a max-min issue, like the +peak value of a 20uS surge waveform. Thx for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "noise floor is -120dB" is not precisely defined as we don't know exactly what the REFERENCE level is.  Do they mean 120dB below average signal level?  Do they mean 120dB below Full Scale?  For that reason, you can't really derive a voltage level. Perhaps the context would be helpful to better understand the statement. But as an isolated phrase, IMHO, it approaches "weasel words".