# Meaning of dB while dealing with amplifier(Op-Amp)

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, decibel

I have found a question in `MIT open-course material`.The question is to

> Design an amplifier(Op-Amp) with a gain of 20dB

While searching about `db` in the Internet I have found out that 20db is defined as follows:(in this case they are dealing with sound wave)
*20dB = 10log(100I<sub>0</sub>/I<sub>0</sub>)*

But The `MIT open-course material` has  provided answer .While dealing with `dB`it approaches as follows:
*From the definition of dB we have: 20dB = 20log(V<sub>out</sub>/V<sub>in</sub>)*

But, from my above searching it should be 
*20dB = 10log(V<sub>out</sub>/V<sub>in</sub>)*

Moreover the questioner of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231957/exact-meaning-of-db) question says that `db` in amplifier is meant to be 10*log(Pout/Pin). What is the thing I am missing here?(which factor? 10 OR 20?)

Link to MIT material is [Here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-071j-introduction-to-electronics-signals-and-measurement-spring-2006/lecture-notes/22_op_amps1.pdf) (Page-20)

Comment: *10log(100I0/I0)* is nonsense. Where did you read that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some common dB values for voltage amplification:

20dB gain => \$10^{\left(\frac{20}{20}\right)}=10\$

6dB gain => \$10^{\left(\frac{6}{20}\right)}≈2\$

3dB gain => \$10^{\left(\frac{3}{20}\right)}≈\sqrt2\$

As you might have noticed, the way to convert voltage gain in dB to linear numbers is to simply use this equation:  \$f(x)=10^{\left(\frac{X}{20}\right)}\$

When you are talking about voltage gain you calculate the dB to \$20×\log\left(\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\right)\$, when you are talking about power gain, then it's \$10×\log\left(\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}\right)\$. They are *essentially* the same thing, just keep your tongue in the correct mouth and everything will be easy peasy. The difference is that the voltage gain calculation assumes that R is the same which leads to the current, \$I\$ being the same, which is not always the case. So that's why the power equation is still there.

**And here's why!**

\$P=V×I\$ and \$I=\frac{V}{R}\$, if you replace the \$I\$ in the first equation you get \$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\$

So the original equation for power gain is \$10×\log\left(\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}\right)\$, which is the same as:

$$10×\log\left(\frac{\frac{V_{out}^2}{R}}{\frac{V_{in}^2}{R}}\right)$$

The R cancel each other out. So you get:

$$10×\log\left(\frac{V_{out}^2}{V_{in}^2}\right)$$

And that can be rewritten like this:

$$10×\log\left(\left(\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\right)^2\right)$$

And this is a logarithmic function, which means we can put the exponent in front of the logarithm.

$$2×10×\log\left(\left(\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\right)\right)$$

And that leaves us with the *other* equation, which is the same thing.

$$20×\log\left(\left(\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Oh . I see . but why factor for power gain and voltage gain differ from each other ? Can you give me any hint ?

Comment: The Square................means "20" is the factor.

Comment: Edit my answer if you don't see it fit.

Answer (score 1):

Decibels are by definition a ratio of powers. This is the \$ 10log(P1/P2) \$ form of the equation.

When the two powers are based on the same impedance then a shortcut to expressing the dBs as a ratio of their voltages is the \$20log (E1/E2) \$ form of the equation. But this is valid *only* if the two voltages are expressed across the same impedance.

Answer (score 0):

> Meaning of db while dealing with amplifier(Op-Amp)

I know this question has been answered and accepted but it's worth remembering that the decibel (deci-bel) is one tenth of a bel and so, when comparing powers in bels, we calculate the bels as: -

log(P1/P2). This is the basic ratio.

If we want decibels then it's: -

10 times log (P1/P2).

For a ratio of voltages we remember that P = V^2/R and, if R is the same value for P1 and P2 we can write that the decibels are: -

10 log(V1\$^2\$/V2\$^2\$) or 10 log(V1/V2)\$^2\$ or 20 log(V1/V2)